# Network error at create error in React and Redux

Tags: react-redux, axios

I'm using React Redux with a PHP/MySQL backend. The Axios call is rendering network error.

I'm not sure what is causing it it, as it works in Postman, but not in the code. The following is my code, is the code wrong? In network I don't get the response 404 is shown and its a non secure site (which has to be used). If I use other internet domain for JSON sample data it works. But then not for the one I'm using. Is it the domain not allowing access?

```
             //const URL=config.INABU;
               // console.log(URL)
                return axios('http://abc.xyz.pes/bu',{
                    method:'GET',
                    headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                }
                })
                .then(response=>{
                    console.log(response)
                })
                .catch(error=>{   console.log(error,error.response,error.data.error.message)
                    throw error;})
```

Is it the back-end causing the issue or at front-end?

I do have other aPI's with http those work not this one.The once working is after index have "?" for get request but the not working its all abc/ghi/pqr/xyz the issue is with url path .Do you think so?

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Check for CORS setting in back-end.

Comment: @KrinaSoni  The backend  says they have set. If the set then where do u think the error is.

Comment: Isn't it because you are getting the info from http and not from https?

Comment: @Jalil I do have other aPI's with http those work not this one.The once working is after index have "?" for get request but the not working its all abc/ghi/pqr/xyz the issue is with  url path .Do you think so?

Comment: No, I don't think so. Maybe its the CORS settings, do you have access to the API code?

Comment: @Jalil  No I don't have access :(

Comment: Can you show us the code you get?